# Не ведает (?) что творит (?) и... . Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

В разных уголках Интернета встретил разное:

> А хирурги разные бывают. Я тот, который не ведает, что творит и
> постоянно ошибается.
>
> Они не ведают, что творят, и будут изблеваны в день Страшного суда.
>
> В принципе, они не ведают, что творят, и сами от этого страдают.

Где-то встретил отсутствие запятых и слева от "что творят", и справа.
Как разобраться?

Comment: Как разобраться? Попробуйте сделать грамматический разбор предложения, которое вас затрудняет. Здесь нет ничего сложного.

Comment: Не могу. Я даже не понимаю, ЧТО Вы порекомендовали. Я бы поставил запятую после "творит". Правил не знаю, а просто так слышу. Написание без запятых вообще не понимаю.

Comment: Это прекрасно, что у вас хороший слух, но иногда произношение не совпадает с постановкой знака.  Как вы думаете, нужна ли запятая в этом предложении:  Я тот, который не ведает, что творит и в чем ошибается.

Comment: Вот здесь не надо. Как это правильно сказать... это всё относится к "не ведает". У меня такое чувство, что я Шариков или свинья, перед которой мечут бисер. Мало знаю.

Comment: Все правильно! То есть в первом предложении ошибка, запятая там нужна. А я вот тоже не психолог, но вижу кое-что. Думаю, что вам нравятся вские розыгрыши, стилизация речи,  и все-такое. Наверное, вы артист по натуре, да?

Comment: Написание без запятых можно объяснить тем, что "не ведает что творит", вероятно, может восприниматься как фразеологический оборот.

Comment: Думаете, к деятельности хирурга можно применить фразеологию?

Comment: Жаль! Но, возможно,  все перемены в нашей жизни  к лучшему. Так что... Скорей туда, куда никто не звал,
Где шум толпы и сигаретный дым,
Где наши судьбы крутит карнавал...

Comment: Ой, а я уже всё удалил. Следы заметаю. Да, я обособился за последнее время, а надо к людям идти. Это верно. И побольше молчать. Пусть говорят Мудрецы!

Comment: Вы забавный...  Любите заметать следы. В наше время это совершенно необходимо. Но уж совсем-то не потеряйтесь, а то сами себя не найдете.

Comment: Всё сбудется! Стоит только расхотеть! :)) http://oteatre.info/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/5.jpg